# Regex Confusion JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to match the following the path below with a regex:

`path = "/r/356363/"`

that looks like:

`regex = RegExp("^\/r\/\d+\/$")`

However, whenever I run `test`, I do

`regex.test(path)`

which returns

`false`

Why doesn't the regex match the path?

To me the regex says, find a string that starts with a /r/, has atleast one digit after, and ends in a /.

I checked the regex in http://regex101.com/#javascript and it appears as a match which leads me more confused.

Comment: Do this in the console and see why: `regex = RegExp("^\/r\/\d+\/$")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you need to escape the escapes; the first `\` escapes the following character *in the string*, you need a second `\` to escape the subsequent `\` *for the RegExp itself*:

```
var path = "/r/356363/",
    regex = RegExp("^\\/r\\/\\d+/$");
console.log(regex.test(path));
```

```js
var path = "/r/356363/",
    regex = RegExp("^\\/r\\/\\d+\\/$");
console.log(regex.test(path));
```

Comment: Wow, that snippet stuff doesn't make the markup more readable... Or editable.

Comment: There is no need to escape `/`, it's not a special character. This should be enough: `var regex = new RegExp("^/r/\\d+/$")`.

Comment: @Rudie: I'm not sure how much it's meant to, really; but yes: it's slightly awkward to play with it (unlike JS Fiddle, JS Bin et al).

Comment: @DavidThomas Why would it do that? The regex is between quotes, it is treated as a string.

Comment: @Gergo: finally edited the answer to remove the unnecessary escapes. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
RegExp("^\/r\/\d+\/$").test('/r/124/') === false
```

but if you use the regex literal writing:

```
/^\/r\/\d+\/$/.test('/r/124/') === true
```

While the forward slashes need to be escaped in the literal version, they don't need to be in the object version.
**However**, backward slashes need to be escaped in the object version (not in the literal version). So you could also have written:

```
RegExp("^/r/\\d+/$").test('/r/124/') === true
```

The issue is that you have used a syntax that works only with the literal version.